# fire trigger after insert in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-xe

I'm very new for trigger,  now this what i was trying. I've two tables **INSERTED** and **ORDER_INFO**, both have the same column name **ORDER_ID**, **ORDER_DATE**. I've scenario, where client will be placing his/her order then, order information will be stored into **INSERTED** table, then by using this trigger, it'll insert into another table **ORDER_INFO** after satisfying the condition, which has been written.

```
    create trigger tri_check
AFTER INSERT ON inserted FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 v_date DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT order_date INTO v_date FROM inserted;
if (v_date)< (sysdate + 2) then
 raiserror('You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now',16, 1);
else
INSERT INTO orders_info
     ( order_id,order_date)
    VALUES
     (:new.order_id,v_date);
end if;
end;
```

But, when i'm executing the above trigger, then i'm getting this error.

```
ERROR at line 8: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6.     SELECT order_date INTO v_date FROM inserted;
7. if (v_date)< (sysdate + 2) then
8.  raiserror('You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now',16, 1);
9. else
10. INSERT INTO orders_info
```

**EDIT**

Now, i made the same structure table into **SYSTEM** user, and got the same error. `Table or View does not exist`

Need help !! Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message seems to indicate a problem with the 'raiserror' procedure.  I'm not familiar with such a procedure in standard PL/SQL - did you mean RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR?  However, and perhaps more to the point, when using a trigger there's no need to do a SELECT from the table.  All the data being inserted is available to the trigger.  I suggest changing your trigger to be something like the following:

```
create trigger tri_check
  AFTER INSERT ON inserted
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if :new.ORDER_DATE < sysdate + INTERVAL '2' DAY then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now');
  else
    INSERT INTO orders_info
      (order_id, order_date)
    VALUES
      (:new.order_id, :new.ORDER_DATE);
  end if;
end TRI_CHECK;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: `ERROR at line 5: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
3.   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
4.   FOR EACH ROW
5. BEGIN
6.   if :new.ORDER_DATE < (sysdate + 2) then
7.     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now');`

Comment: @sql_query - Does the INSERTED table exist in your current schema? And is the table name in upper case or is it specifically in lower case? If it's lower case you'll need to enclose the table name in double-quotes (i.e. AFTER INSERT ON "inserted"). IMO lower case or CamelCase table names are more bother than they're worth. YMMV.

Comment: Yes, off-course, if you want the screenshot, then i can show you.

Comment: `ERROR at line 7: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
5.    IF :new.order_date < (SYSDATE + 2)
6.    THEN
7.        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now');
8.    ELSE
9.       INSERT INTO orders_info (order_id, order_date)`

Comment: I found the problem, it was just due to mentioning wrong table name `order_info`. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `:NEW` and `:OLD` values instead of your select:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri_check
   AFTER INSERT
   ON inserted
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF :new.order_date < (SYSDATE + 2)
   THEN
      raiserror (
         'You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now',
         16,
         1);
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO orders_info (order_id, order_date)
      VALUES (:new.order_id, :new.order_date);
   END IF;
END;
```

What is your `raiserror` procedure? Do you have access permissions granted on it?

Hope it helps...

**EDIT:**

OK, from your error, and the error you posted on @Bob Jarvis' answer, you might not have `INSERT` privilege on the `ORDERS_INFO` table. You also should check your permissions on the `INSERTED` table too.

Check your permissions with your DBA.

If `raiserror` is not a defined procedure or you don't have access to it then use the [RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm) method for raising an error as Bob suggests.

Comment: `ERROR at line 7: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5. DECLARE
6. BEGIN
7.    IF :new.order_date < (SYSDATE + 2)
8.    THEN
9.       raiserror ('You cannot take an order to be delivered less than 2 days from now',16,1);
`

Comment: OK, could you answer my question about your `raiserror` procedure please?

Comment: i don't know, i just got the some part of the code from my friend and using it, in my own scenario. If you know other than that, then you can tell

Comment: How would I know what procedures and permissions your friend has or anything about your scenario as you have not described anything other than your trigger? Did you create the database? Did you create the tables `INSERTED` and `ORDERS_INFO`? If so you have permissions on them, if not speak to whoever did create them to grant you the relevent permissions.

Comment: Now, granted all the permission, to my database, but, still showing the error `table or view does not exist`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact code you used to grant the permissions? It will help a lot. Did you grant the permissions as a different user from the one you are creating the trigger as? Also, please show the exact error message too.

Comment: I'm using Oracle XE,which provides the UI, so didn't write anycode for that, i just navigate to grant option where i grant all the permission putting HR as a grantee.